# mod_jk with Tomcat 6 and HTTP Authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat6, mod-jk

Are there any gotchas using ModJK to forward to an application protected by standard HTTP Authentication?

We have two web apps installed on our Tomcat 6.0.14, one is the standard Tomcat Manager while the other is the standard Tomcat sample application.

We can get to the sample application but the Tomcat manager doesn't work. The Tomcat logs show a 401 error.

Comment: Have you tried to set the same username to the tomcat manager and the apache basic auth?

Comment: Post your `conf/tomcat-users.xml` file?